# How to resolve the error "deselaers/logos/rwthaachenuniversity-whitegray not found" in beamer poster?

Tags: texstudio, beamerposter

I was using the following code for preparation of a poster in Latex using **TeXstudio 2.6.6**

```
\documentclass[final,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{I6pd2}}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,latexsym}
\boldmath
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}
\newcommand{\R}{{\mathbb R}}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered tabularx columns
\newcommand{\pphantom}{\textcolor{ta3aluminium}} % phantom introduces a vertical space in p formatted table columns??!!
\listfiles
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
 \title{\huge Comparisons of   $B_{row}$-splittings  of Matrices}
\author{ \vspace{.2cm} {\bf \large{ author}}\\ \vspace{.2cm} Research Supervisor- prof john\\ \vspace{.2cm} School of statistics}
\institute{institute name}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newlength{\columnheight}
\setlength{\columnheight}{105cm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.49\textwidth}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[center,wd=\textwidth]{postercolumn}
    \begin{minipage}[T]{.95\textwidth}  % tweaks the width, makes a new \textwidth
      \parbox[t][\columnheight]{\textwidth}{
        \begin{block}{INTRODUCTION}
In many practical problems we come across the problem of computing a 
solution to a system of linear equations in $n$ unknowns \textcolor{blue}
{\begin{eqnarray}\label{eq0}
Ax=b,\end{eqnarray}
}
where $A$ is a real rectangular $m\times n$ matrix and $b$ is a real $m$-vector.
 In a wide variety of such problems, including the Neumann problem  and those 
for elastic bodies with free surfaces, the finite difference formulations lead to 
a singular, consistent linear system (\ref{eq0}) where $A$ is large and sparse.
 Here the general method of solution is iterative in nature. Iterative methods
 where $A$ is rectangular or inconsistent, have been studied
in \cite{bpcones}. The authors  used generalized matrix
inverses for computing least square solutions in the inconsistent
\textcolor{blue}{
\begin{eqnarray}\label{eq01}
x^{(i+1)}=U^{\dag}Vx^{(i)}+U^{\dag}b,
\end{eqnarray}
}
where $U^{\dag}$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse of $U$.
 \vspace{.5cm}
The above scheme is said to be convergent if the spectral radius of
$U^{\dag}V$ is less than 1. For a proper splitting, the authors of 
\cite{bpcones} have shown that  $x=A^{\dag}b$ for any initial
vector $x^{0}$ if and only if (\ref{eq01}) is convergent.
\end{block}
        \vfill
        \begin{block}{PRELIMINARIES}
\textcolor{darkgreen}{Moore-Penrose inverse}\\
The  Moore-Penrose inverse of $A\in {\R}^{m\times n}$
is the unique matrix $A^{\dag}\in {\R}^{n\times m}$ that satisfies the following four    
equations:
$$AA^{\dag}A=A,~~~~A^{\dag}AA^{\dag}=A^{\dag},~~~~(AA^{\dag})^{T}=AA^{\dag}~~\mbox{and}
~~(A^{\dag}A)^{T}=A^{\dag}A.$$
If $A^{\dag}\geq 0$, then it is semimonotone. Berman and Plemmons, \cite{bpmonotono}  
showed that
 $A^{\dag}\geq 0$  if and only if $ Ax\in {\R}^m_+ +N(A^T) ~~\mbox{and}~~x \in
R(A^{T})$ imply  $x\geq 0.$ 

\textcolor{darkgreen}{Row monotone matrix}\\
 $A\in {\R}^{m\times n}$ is said to be row monotone \cite{bpmonotono} if  $ Ax\geq 0   
~~\mbox{and}~~x \in
R(A^{T})$ imply  $x\geq 0.$ \\  

$A$ is row monotone if and only if $A$ is 
$\{1,4\}$-monotone. ($\{1,4\}$-monotone means there is a nonnegative $G$ satisfying  
$AGA=A$ and $(GA)^T=GA$.)
If $A^{\dag} \geq 0$,  then $A$ and $A^T$ are  row monotone. 
However, the converse is not true. \\

 A  decomposition $A=U-V$ of $A\in {\R}^{m\times n}$ is called 
 \textcolor{blue}{{\it positive}}  if $U\geq 0$ and $V\geq 0$. \\
\vspace{.2cm}

\textcolor{darkgreen}{ $B_{row}$-splitting (Definition 2.6, \cite{mis})}\\
A positive   proper splitting $A=U-V$ of $A\in {\R}^{m\times n}$ is called a $B_{row}$-  
splitting if it satisfies the following conditions: \\
(i) $VU^{\dag}\geq 0$, and \\
(ii) $ Ax,~ Ux\geq 0 ~~\mbox{and}~~x \in R(A^{T})$ imply  $x\geq 0.$\\

\vspace{.2cm}
\textcolor{darkgreen}{Theorem 1} (Theorem 2.7, \cite{mis})\\
Let $A\in {\R}^{m\times n}$. Suppose that $R(A) \cap int(\mathbb{R}^m_+) \neq   
\emptyset$. Consider the following statements:\\
(a) $A$ is row monotone.\\
(b) $ {\R}_{+}^{m}\cap R(A) \subseteq A{\R}_{+}^{n}$.\\
(c) There exists $x^{0}\in {\R}_{+}^{n}$ such that $Ax^{0} \in int({\R}_{+}^{m})$.\\
Then, we have (a) $\Rightarrow$ (b) $\Rightarrow$ (c).\\
Suppose that $A$ has a $B_{row}$-splitting. Then each of the above is equivalent to the   
following:\\
(d) $\rho(VU^{\dag})<1$.

\vspace{.2cm}

\textcolor{darkgreen}{Theorem 2} (Theorem 2.12, \cite{mis})\\
Suppose that $A$ is row monotone and $R(A) \cap int({\R}^{m}_{+}) \neq \emptyset$ for   
$A\in {\R}^{m\times n}$.
 Further, let $A^{\dag}A\geq 0$. Then $A$ possesses a  $B_{row}$-splitting $A=U-V$  with     
$\rho(VU^{\dag})<1$.
\end{block}
\vfill
 \begin{block}{OBJECTIVE}
To  present a more general
  convergence theorem for $B_{row}$-splitting and to  compare two $B_{row}$-splittings.
\end{block}
      }
    \end{minipage}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
\end{column}
% ---------------------------------------------------------%
% end the column

% ---------------------------------------------------------%
% Set up a column 
\begin{column}{.49\textwidth}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[center,wd=\textwidth]{postercolumn}
    \begin{minipage}[T]{.95\textwidth} % tweaks the width, makes a new \textwidth
      \parbox[t][\columnheight]{\textwidth}{ % must be some better way to set the the height, width and textwidth simultaneously
        % Since all columns are the same length, it is all nice and tidy.  You have to get the height empirically
        % ---------------------------------------------------------%
        % fill each column with content

       \begin{block}{MAIN RESULTS}
We begin with the following lemma which is useful to prove our main results of this section.
\vspace{.4cm}
\textcolor{yellow}{LEMMA 3}\\
\textcolor{blue}{(a) If $A$ is row monotone, $V\geq 0$ and $R(V)\subseteq R(A)$, then  
$A^{\dag}V\geq 0$.\\
(b) If $A^T$ is row monotone, $V\geq 0$ and $N(A)\subseteq N(V)$, then $VA^{\dag}\geq 
0$.}

\vspace{.4cm}
Now, we obtain a new  convergence theorem for  $B_{row}$-splittings which holds
 even without the assumption $R(A) \cap int({\R}^{m}_{+}) \neq \emptyset$. Thus, the  
present one is more general  than the earlier one (Theorem 2).

\vspace{.4cm}
\textcolor{yellow}{THEOREM  4}\\
\textcolor{blue}{ Let  $A=U-V$ be a  $B_{row}$-splitting of $A\in {\R}^{m\times n}$. If  
$A$ is row monotone,then\\
(a) $A^{\dag}\geq U^{\dag}$;\\
(b) $\rho(VA^{\dag})\geq \rho(VU^{\dag})$;\\
(c) $\rho(VU^{\dag})=\rho(U^{\dag}V)=\frac{\rho(A^{\dag}V)}{1+\rho(A^{\dag}V)}<1$.}

\vspace{.4cm}
Theorem 2 enables us that there exist several $B_{row}$-splittings of a given matrix.
In this direction, we  present  two comparison theorems for  $B_{row}$-splittings.

\vspace{.4cm}
\textcolor{yellow}{THEOREM 5}\\
\textcolor{blue}{ Let  $A=U_{1}-V_{1}=U_{2}-V_{2}$ be two  $B_{row}$-splittings of
$A$. If  $A$ is  row monotone and $V_{2}\geq V_{1}$, then
$$1> \rho(U_{2}^{\dag}V_{2}) \geq \rho(U_{1}^{\dag}V_{1}).$$}

\vspace{.4cm}
\textcolor{yellow}{EXAMPLE 6 }
Let $A=\left(
     \begin{array}{cc}
       1 & 1 \\
       1 & 1 \\
     \end{array}
   \right)
$. Clearly $A$ is row monotone. Setting
$U_{1}=3A$ and $U_{2}=4A$.  We  then have $0\leq V_{1}=2A\leq 3A=V_{2}$.  Hence
$\rho(V_{1}U_{1}^{\dag})=\frac{2}{3}\leq \frac{3}{4}=\rho(V_{2}U_{2}^{\dag})<1$.

\vspace{.4cm}
The condition $V_2\geq V_1$ can not be dropped. For example, set $V_{1}=3A$ and   
$V_{2}=2A$.Then the implication $$\rho(U_{1}^{\dag}V_{1}) \leq \rho(U_{2}^{\dag}V_{2}) <  
1$$ does not hold. Similarly,the assumption  $U_{1}^{\dag}\geq U_{2}^{\dag}$ in the  
Theorem given below can not be dropped.

\vspace{.4cm}
\textcolor{yellow}{THEOREM 7}\\
\textcolor{blue}{ Let $A\in {\R}^{m\times n}$ be such that $A$ and $A^T$ are row   
monotone. Let $A=U_{1}-V_{1}=U_{2}-V_{2}$ also be   two  $B_{row}$-splittings of
$A$.  If $U_{1}^{\dag}\geq U_{2}^{\dag}$,then $$1>\rho(U_{2}^{\dag}V_{2}) \geq  
\rho(U_{1}^{\dag}V_{1}).$$ }
\end{block}
\vfill
\begin{block}{CONCLUSIONS}
A convergence theorem and comparison theorems for  $B_{row}$-splittings are presented. 
\end{block}
\vfill
\begin{block}{PUBLICATIONS}
{Jena, L. and Mishra, D.},
 \emph{Comparisons of   $B_{row}$-splittings and $B_{ran}$-splittings of Matrices},
Linear and Multilinear Algebra, DOI 10.1080/03081087.2012.661426
\end{block}
\vfill
\begin{block}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}
I thank my research supervisor  prof. john    for his  encouragement. 
\end{block}
\vfill
\begin{block}{REFERENCES}


\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{bpcones} {Berman, A.; Plemmons, R. J.},
 \emph{Cones and iterative methods for best square least squares solutions of linear  
systems},SIAM J. Numer. Anal., 11 (1974) 145-154.

\bibitem{bpmonotono} {Berman, A.; Plemmons, R. J.},
\emph{Monotonicity and the generalized inverse},SIAM J. Appl. Math.  22 (1972) 155-161.


\bibitem{mis} {  Mishra, D.;  Sivakumar, K. C.},
\emph{Generalizations of matrix monotonicity and their relationships with 
certain subclasses of proper splittings},
Linear Algebra Appl. DOI:10.1016/j.laa.2011.11.016 .

\bibitem{per} {Peris, J. E.},
 \emph{A new characterization of inverse-positive matrices}, 
Linear Algebra Appl.  154/156  (1991) 45-58.

\bibitem{var} {Varga, R. S.},
\emph{Matrix Iterative Analysis},  Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 2000.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{block}
}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
\end{column}
% ---------------------------------------------------------%
% end the column
\end{columns}
  \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

I am getting the following errors

```
File `deselaers/logos/rwthaachenuniversity-whitegray' not found. 
Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `darkgreen' \end{frame}
Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `darkgreen' \end{frame}
Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `darkgreen' \end{frame}
Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `darkgreen' \end{frame}
Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `darkgreen' \end{frame}
File `deselaers/logos/rwthaachenuniversity-whitegray' not found. \end{frame}
```

I don't know why these errors are there.
I need the help of experts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to have the latest version of `beamerthemeI6pd2.sty` downloadable at https://github.com/jtanderson/Fish-Poster/blob/master/beamerthemeI6pd2.sty.

Then pass the option `svgnames` to `xcolor` through `beamer`, that means load `beamer` as

```
\documentclass[final,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false},xcolor={svgnames}]{beamer}
```

After that, replace all instances of `darkgreen` with `DarkGreen` in your document and it should compile fine.

Then you'll probably have to adjust something in your document.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir It works fine now. Sir I want to change the background color what command i should give in the code? Also I want it in ao size and landscape form.

Comment: @Litun put the line `\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=tachameleon, bg=ta3gray}` in your document and change `ta3gray` to whatever you like. The document is already in a0 landscape size. BTW. remember that you can accept (and upvote) the answer if it helped you.

Comment: I've accepted and upvoted your answer. Thank you for your quick reply. what are the alternatives for **ta3gray** that i can use to change color.

Comment: @Litun for example the ones you find in the `xcolor` [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf), section 4.3, p.38.